# 'rake aborted!' Stuck on gitimmersion tutorial

Tags: command-line, git, ruby

I am going through the Git Immersion tutorial on Lab 21 here:

http://gitimmersion.com/lab_21.html

After I had installed Rake and created the 'Rakefile' with the contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -wKU

task :default => :run

task :run do
  require './lib/hello'
end
```

running the `rake` command from the terminal returns:

```
rake aborted!
/home/azali/Documents/Brogramming/git_tutorial/work/hello/lib/hello.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected $end
/home/azali/Documents/Brogramming/git_tutorial/work/hello/Rakefile:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => default => run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Why is this error occurring when I am just following the instructions on the tutorial? Is there something that I am missing in either files?

The contents of my `hello.rb` file:

```
# Default is "World"
# Author: Progoogler
puts Hello, World
puts Hello, #{ARGV.first}!
name = ARGV.first || "World"
puts Hello, #{name}!
```

My current version of Rake is 10.0.4.
My current version of Ruby is 1.9.3p484.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and then realized that my `Rakefile` was created in the wrong directory -- i.e. I had made my `Rakefile` in the **`lib`** directory, when it actually needed to be in the **`hello`** directory.
As soon as you move the file, the problem is solved.